# Cann't delete the CSV file after imported by Feeds module

Tags: feeds, media

We uninstalled the "Feeds" and "Job Scheduler" modules, after a successful imported csv data by Feeds. However, the csv file is still maintained in "media" list. When we try to delete that file, it say "The file xxx.csv is in use and cannot be deleted". Is there a way to delete that, or do we have to delete from FTP?

Comment: Have you run update.php to update the database after removing the module?

Comment: Ya, we did the update database after removed the module. It still unable to delete.

Answer (score 2):

The "file still in use and cannot be deleted" means Drupal's still managing the file, so don't remove it via FTP because that basically bypasses Drupal and could cause other issues related to Drupal expecting a file to be somewhere and it's suddenly not there. So I'd recommend finding a solution that involves working via the UI and not directly on the file system.

Is the file attached as a field to an item of content somewhere? That would result in "file still in use". If so, delete the item of content, clear cache a few times and check again.

Comment: The only time we used that file was imported by "Feeds" module. And the Feeds module has been uninstalled.

Comment: @H-L uninstalling module does not remove it's usage marks on files. It should probably be used to delete file, if it's the one that uploaded it.

Comment: It may used when to "delete file" when running "Feeds" module. But I already uninstalled the Feeds. There should be a way to delete that, because that csv data already imported into database.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, run the file through `file_usage_list()` to be absolutely sure it's not used anywhere else. You never know.

If only Feeds comes back as a result, you can then always run the file through `file_delete()`, though you'll have to use the `$force` parameter.

Comment: Sorry Vodde, I'm not a developer. But I really want to know how to run "file_usage_list()"

Comment: The easiest way to do that, would be to install the Devel module. After doing that, you can run PHP by browsing to devel/php, type the required code and press submit.

This should pretty much do it:
`$fid = [file_id];`
`$file = file_load($fid);`
`dpm(file_usage_list($file));`

You'll have to find the file's ID first though, and replace '[file_id]' with that number.
Another option is to access your DB and browse in the `file_usage` table, again using the file's ID and look at the value listed under 'module'